# C++ method demands reference, can't get Cython to provide one

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, cython

I am interfacing Python to a C++ library called Bullet Physics, via Cython. I have quite a bit of it working but one issue is vexing me. Here is an example of a problem that occurs in multiple contexts.

A Bullet Physics .h file declares a method, which I copy and incorporate into my cdefs like this:

```
cdef cppclass btSliderConstraint:
    btSliderConstraint *btSliderConstraint(btRigidBody& rbA, btRigidBody& rbB, const btTransform& frameInA, const btTransform& frameInB, bool useLinearReferenceFrameA)
```

The problem is how to specify the rbA and rbB *references* (the & rbA and & rbB) in a Cython call to this method . I have lots of pointers to btRigidBody objects floating around, but the declaration of this method demands the arguments be *references* (unless I am mistaken).

If I try to just supply pointers to btRigidBody objects for rbA and rbB, the cython compiler complains, fairly understandably, with:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
    cdef btRigidBody *b1
    cdef btRigidBody *b2
    # bs.bodies is an array of pointers to btRigidBody objects, nbi and ji1 are integer indices
    b1 = bs.bodies[nbi]
    b2 = bs.bodies[ji1]
    motor = new btSliderConstraint(b1, b2, tra, trb, 1);
                                        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

fun4.pyx:922:41: Cannot assign type 'btRigidBody *' to 'btRigidBody'
```

None of my attempts to cast or dereference or the like have made this work. It seems like this is easy to do in plain C++ but in Cython nothing I've tried seems to work.

If I were able to simply declare a variable of type btRigidBody, like this:

cdef btRigidBody rbA

then I am confident I could pass that as an argument and the compiler would not complain. I do this in other contexts and it works. However, I do not want to do this here because I already have a pointer to the object that I want to pass as the argument, and also, doing things this way would require that a "nullarity constructor" exist for the btRigidBody object and the library does not provide a constructor that takes no arguments, and I do not want to make modifications to the library for reasons of maintainability.

So, how can I convert the pointers to a btRigidBody objects that I have, to btRigidBody references that I need, in Cython?

Edit:

The obvious use of * to dereference the pointer does not work in Cython (though I think it would work in C++). In Cython it gives a slew of confusing errors:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef btRigidBody *b1
    cdef btRigidBody *b2
    # bs.bodies is an array of pointers to btRigidBody objects, nbi and ji1 are integer indices
    b1 = bs.bodies[nbi]
    b2 = bs.bodies[ji1]
    motor = new btSliderConstraint(*b1, *b2, tra, trb, 1);
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

fun4.pyx:922:34: Non-trivial keyword arguments and starred arguments not allowed in cdef functions.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef btRigidBody *b1
    cdef btRigidBody *b2
    # bs.bodies is an array of pointers to btRigidBody objects, nbi and ji1 are integer indices
    b1 = bs.bodies[nbi]
    b2 = bs.bodies[ji1]
    motor = new btSliderConstraint(*b1, *b2, tra, trb, 1);
                                     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

fun4.pyx:922:38: Cannot convert 'btRigidBody *' to Python object

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef btRigidBody *b1
    cdef btRigidBody *b2
    # bs.bodies is an array of pointers to btRigidBody objects, nbi and ji1 are integer indices
    b1 = bs.bodies[nbi]
    b2 = bs.bodies[ji1]
    motor = new btSliderConstraint(*b1, *b2, tra, trb, 1);
                                          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

fun4.pyx:922:43: Cannot convert 'btRigidBody *' to Python object

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef btRigidBody *b1
    cdef btRigidBody *b2
    # bs.bodies is an array of pointers to btRigidBody objects, nbi and ji1 are integer indices
    b1 = bs.bodies[nbi]
    b2 = bs.bodies[ji1]
    motor = new btSliderConstraint(*b1, *b2, tra, trb, 1);
                                               ^
------------------------------------------------------------

fun4.pyx:922:48: Cannot convert 'btTransform' to Python object

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef btRigidBody *b1
    cdef btRigidBody *b2
    # bs.bodies is an array of pointers to btRigidBody objects, nbi and ji1 are integer indices
    b1 = bs.bodies[nbi]
    b2 = bs.bodies[ji1]
    motor = new btSliderConstraint(*b1, *b2, tra, trb, 1);
                                                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

fun4.pyx:922:53: Cannot convert 'btTransform' to Python object

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef btRigidBody *b1
    cdef btRigidBody *b2
    # bs.bodies is an array of pointers to btRigidBody objects, nbi and ji1 are integer indices
    b1 = bs.bodies[nbi]
    b2 = bs.bodies[ji1]
    motor = new btSliderConstraint(*b1, *b2, tra, trb, 1);
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

fun4.pyx:922:34: Cannot convert Python object to 'btSliderConstraint *'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef btRigidBody *b1
    cdef btRigidBody *b2
    # bs.bodies is an array of pointers to btRigidBody objects, nbi and ji1 are integer indices
    b1 = bs.bodies[nbi]
    b2 = bs.bodies[ji1]
    motor = new btSliderConstraint(*b1, *b2, tra, trb, 1);
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

fun4.pyx:922:34: Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference
```

Comment: "So, how can I convert the pointers to a btRigidBody objects that I have, to btRigidBody references" Dereference them?

Comment: How, Neil? I've tried many things. I will edit the question with an example.

Comment: Using `operator *`

Comment: Question is edited showing what happens when this is done. (I had already tried it, and many other things too.)

Comment: From Cython docs: "Cython uses the normal C syntax for C types, including pointers. ... Note that Cython uses array access for pointer dereferencing, as *x is not valid Python syntax" ... I think I may have solved this, at long last.

Comment: I think I better understand why * does not work, but so far my attempts to accomplish the dereference still do not compile.

Comment: This actually compiles:  motor = new btSliderConstraint(bs.bodies[nbi][0], bs.bodies[ji1][0], tra, trb, 1);
I'm testing it now.

Comment: Thanks Neil, your comments did give me some help in finding the right search terms.

Answer (score 5):

Because of Cython's goal of preserving Python syntax, it wasn't possible to use * for pointer dereference. Instead [] is used. The following does what is desired:

motor = new btSliderConstraint(bs.bodies[nbi][0], bs.bodies[ji1][0], tra, trb, 1);